# Memory leak while handling Foundation Object from NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, memory-leaks, nsjsonserialization

I'm struggling to fix a memory leak in a helper function I have made. The helper function takes the result of

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
```

and converts all the leaf elements into NSStrings if they are NSNumbers.

Here is the method:

```
-(NSArray *) stringisizeObjects:(NSArray *)inputArray{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *mutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[inputArray count]];

    for (int i = 0; i < [inputArray count]; i++) {
        NSArray *keys = [inputArray[i] allKeys];

        NSMutableDictionary *addDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[keys count]];

        for (int j = 0; j < [keys count]; j++) {

            id theObject = [[inputArray[i] objectForKey:keys[j]]autorelease];

            if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {

                [addDictionary setObject:[theObject stringValue] forKey:keys[j]];
                [theObject release];

            }else if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
                [addDictionary setObject:[inputArray[i] objectForKey:keys[j]] forKey:keys[j]];
            }

        }
        [mutable addObject:addDictionary];
    }
    NSArray *returnArray = [mutable copy];

    [mutable removeAllObjects];
    [mutable release];
    [pool drain];
    return returnArray;
}
```

Here is how I get the input array.

```
id parsedThingy = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:resultJSONData options:1 error:&jsonDecodeError];
```

Before I can pass the result to my stringisize method I must ensure that I have an NSArray of NSDictionaries with matching keys.

```
NSArray *resultArray = [self stringisizeObjects:parsedThingy];
```

The X-Code memory leaks tool has pointed me to this method as the cause of my problem.

[Instruments showing leaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTIHR.png)

As you can see I have tried wrapping things in autorelease pools, autoreleasing and releasing. I just don't see any way forward here.

This is a non ARC project that runs 24/7.

Edit: I took the advice from Droppy and tried to re-write the method using mutableCopy. The leak is still there. At this point my only work around maybe to change the source of the JSON to send only strings. :(

```
-(NSArray *) stringisizeObjects2:(NSArray *)inputArray{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [inputArray mutableCopy];

    for (int i = 0; i < [mutableArray count]; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [mutableArray[i] mutableCopy];
        NSArray *keys = [mutableDict allKeys];

        for (int j = 0; j < [keys count]; j++) {
            if ([[mutableDict objectForKey:keys[j]] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
                NSString *stringValue = [[mutableDict objectForKey:keys[j]] stringValue];

                [mutableDict removeObjectForKey:keys[j]];
                [mutableDict setObject:stringValue  forKey:keys[j]];
            }
        }
        mutableArray[i] = [mutableDict copy];
        [mutableDict release];
    }

    NSArray *returnArray = [mutableArray copy];

    [mutableArray release];
    [pool drain];
    return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a lot of code that could be replaced with `mutableCopy`.

Comment: I faced same problem of memory leaking in arrays. I was adding images in NSMutableArray. Even, I removed all objects like you did, it still leaks. You can do nothing for it because it depends on Xcode to clear memory. It do when it wants. But to avoid it's affects, you can can divide your code and run some parts on main queue and some on background queue depending on your needs.

Comment: in your origin code change NSMutableArray *mutable = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[inputArray count]] autorelease]; and add [addDictionary release]; right after [mutable addObject:addDictionary]; and return mutable;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem:

1. `addDictionary` called `alloc` but not call `release` or `autorelease`
2. returnArray = [mutable copy]; // did increase retainCount +1, need `autorelease` here
3. `id theObject = [inputArray[i] objectForKey:keys[j]];` // not need autorelease or release for object that You not own
4. add NSAutoreleasePool to top an bottom here just do nothing

solution:

```
-(NSArray *) stringisizeObjects:(NSArray *)inputArray{
    NSMutableArray *mutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[inputArray count]];

    for (int i = 0; i < [inputArray count]; i++) {
        NSArray *keys = [inputArray[i] allKeys];

        NSMutableDictionary *addDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[keys count]];

        for (int j = 0; j < [keys count]; j++) {

            id theObject = [inputArray[i] objectForKey:keys[j]]; // not need autorelease

            if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {

                [addDictionary setObject:[theObject stringValue] forKey:keys[j]];
                //[theObject release]; // not need release value here

            }else if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
                [addDictionary setObject:[inputArray[i] objectForKey:keys[j]] forKey:keys[j]];
            }

        }
        [mutable addObject:addDictionary];
        [addDictionary release]; // release after not use
    }
    NSArray *returnArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutable] autorelease]; // auto release for return value

    [mutable removeAllObjects];
    [mutable release];
    return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks A Báo I think this has done the job.

It is giving me problems with another AutoRelease pool further out.

I'll work on it and mark this as correct when I get it working.

Comment: @DavidP I've edited answer for  //not need autorelease or release for object that You not own. Try new code

Comment: Thanks @A Báo this really got me on the right path. There is another leak in the function before this one. The X-Code instruments is identifying it in the NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData method.
I think that is a different question.